# Cyanide hydrolysis; could it yield an oxime?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, hydrolysis, nitriles

The mechanisms for both acid and base catalyzed hydrolysis of nitriles are clear;
[image]

(With the subsequent deprotonation from the hydroxyl) and

[image]

([Source](https://www.chemistrysteps.com/the-mechanism-of-nitrile-hydrolysis-to-carboxylic-acid/))

In both cases, the hydroxyl adds to the carbon while the proton adds to the nitrogen.

I thought up an alternate mechanism, with the proton attaching to the carbon, and the hydroxyl going to the thereby positively-charged nitrogen, yielding an oxime.

Why doesn't this occur? I thought of the fact that the nitrogen atom, with a lone pair, would cause any nearby protons to come straight to it, but I'd like clarification on that.

Comment: Well, nitrogen is the electronegative atom here and it has the lone pair as you mentioned, so its very unlikely that the proton will go to the carbon

Answer (score -2):

Yes, since nitrogen is more electronegative than carbon, and also since it has the lone pair available for taking, the proton is likelier to go to it.